# Dlib face detection terrible performance on C++, good in python, why?

Tags: python, c++, dlib

I am trying to write a simple face detection algorithm using OpenCV for camera capture and Dlib for face detection (using Histogram of Oriented Gradients algorithm).

Using Python, I get a decent performance with around 20 fps.
However, the same-ish code in C++ has very poor performance, with each dlib's detection process taking around 4 seconds.

Does anyone know what's happening ?

I did some optimization, but nothing really improve performances :

- image is reduced to 640x480
- I compiled dlib with AVX instructions enabled
- I also tried to compile with -0fast flag...

Here are the codes:

In C++:

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <dlib/opencv.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

int main(){

cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
vector<cv::Rect> facesCV;
vector<rectangle> faces;
frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
cv::namedWindow("test");
cv::Mat frame, small;

if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "Unable to connect to camera" << endl;
    return 1;
}

while (true) {
    // Grab a frame
    if (!cap.read(frame)) {
        break;
    }
    cv::resize(frame, small, {640, 480});
    cv_image<rgb_pixel> cimg(small);

    // Detect faces
    faces = detector(cimg);
    for (auto &f : faces) {
        facesCV.emplace_back(cv::Point((int) f.left(), (int) f.top()), cv::Point((int) f.right(), (int) f.bottom()));
    }

    for (auto &r : facesCV) {
        cv::rectangle(small, r, {0, 255, 0}, 2);
    }
    cv::imshow("test", small);
    cv::waitKey(1);
    faces.clear();
    facesCV.clear();
}
}
```

In Python :

```
import argparse
import cv2
import dlib

#initialize face detector
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

#initialize video source
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
window = cv2.namedWindow("camera")

while True:
    ret, image = cam.read()
    if ret is True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray =cv2.resize(gray, (640, 480))

        for r in detector(gray, 0):
            cv2.rectangle(image, (r.left(), r.top()), (r.right(), r.bottom()), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv2.imshow(window, image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    else:
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Are compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio? (I think you need the full MSDN version, not the Community Edition).  If so, it has an excellent profiler.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio, I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 based Linux Mint), Isaw there is a Linux version of Visual Studio, does it come with the profiler ?

I added my compilation options in my post.

Comment: Solution found ! The compilation option was not properly handled by CLion IDE (or I was not using it properly, probably), compiling outside of the IDE works well.

Comment: @JérômeBruzaud 
In SO you should not add SOLVED to the title of your question or anything similar, what you should do is post an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue came from the CMakeLists.txt. AVX optimizations need to be set in the CMakeLists.txt this way :

```
set(USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS ON CACHE BOOL "Use AVX instructions")
add_subdirectory("path/to/dlib" dlib_build)

add_executable(myProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries( myProject dlib::dlib)
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution wasn't a solution for me.

I was building dlib separately (using the option: `-DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=ON`) and then attempting to build my project with this in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
find_package(dlib REQUIRED)
```

It sort of worked. It was linking to dlib, but for some reason it ran super slow.

To get the most out of dlib I had to:

```
add_subdirectory(../dlib dlib_build)
```

in my CMakeLists.txt file and build ***my*** project as I would have built dlib:

```
cmake -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=ON  ../
cmake --build . --config Release
```